# Add vertical labels on left side of tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, charts, flow-charts, vertical

I have a flowchart using tikz, and I'd like my legend to include a vertical label on the left side of the tikzpicture.

[image]

Like above text. (Excuse my 10 second Paint MS flowchart)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301) It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.  Also, the solution may be dependent on the packages that you are using and how exactly you are creating the flow-chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{farbe}{RGB}{147,131,49}
\tikzstyle{io} = [fill=farbe,inner sep=15pt,circle]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[io] (a) {};
        \node[io,below=2 of a] (b) {};
        \node[io,right=2 of b,yshift=.5cm] (c) {};
            \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c);
        \path (a) -- (b) node[rotate=180,midway,sloped,below=3] {\large SOMETHING TEXTY};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

---

**EDIT:** Is that good? The node stands always on the same position.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\definecolor{farbe}{RGB}{147,131,49}
\tikzstyle{io} = [fill=farbe,inner sep=15pt,circle]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \useasboundingbox (-5,-4.5) rectangle (5,1);
            \node[io] (a) {};
            \node[io,below=2 of a] (b) {};
            \node[io,right=2 of b,yshift=.5cm] (c) {};
                \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c);
            \node[rotate=90] at (-2.7,-1.6) {\large SOMETHING TEXTY};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But now isn't the text going to move, if I reposition B?

Comment: @Louis: It is always in the middle of `a` and `b`; you didn't specify your question, when you want it "stationary", then just position the node at an absolute point.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, completely new to LaTeX. I just want a label like in your image, except it should be stationary. I have no idea how to go about centering it vertically, and floating it to the left.

Comment: The good answer can not be with zero score :-). +1