# Minipages with tilted text vertical middle

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, minipage

I want to make a plot as follows:

[image]

I'm planning to use minipages. However, I don't know how I can include tilted text (as on the left) and how to make it be vertically algined to the middle of the figures. I'd be thankful for an example of how to do that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It's different depends on what you use to plot (TikZ? Could be matplotlib as well), but see [tikz pgf - Add vertical labels on left side of tikzpicture - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/449404/add-vertical-labels-on-left-side-of-tikzpicture) for a similar example

Comment: I would go with a tabular or tabularx, with \multicolumn for the legend and figure captions on the left and \multirow for the captions on the right.

Comment: @user202729 I would like to use matplotlib

Comment: Then just use matplotlib as usual and includegraphics in TeX? The question of to use matplotlib to achieve the functionality is not for this site, however.

Comment: @JohnKormylo do you have a good way of how to insert the labels all the way on the left then. multirow and as pdfs? or is there a better way? Thanks to both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `\caption` starts and ends with par, it was adding two extra blank lines.  `\cramit` makes the caption act like a single line of text.

I used `\raisebox` instead of multirow so I could play with the height adjustment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}% \rotatebox
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\cramit}[1]{\raisebox{0pt}[\ht\strutbox][\dp\strutbox]{%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}#1\end{minipage}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup{skip=0pt, justification=raggedright}%
\tabcolsep=2pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXXX|X}
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}{This is a very Long Legend} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Legend} \\
\raisebox{1cm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{COVID}} &
 \rule{\linewidth}{2cm} & \rule{\linewidth}{2cm} &  \rule{\linewidth}{2cm} &
 \rule{\linewidth}{2cm} \\
& \cramit{\subcaption{Yada}} & \cramit{\subcaption{Yada}} & \cramit{\subcaption{Yada}} & \\[\floatsep]
& \multicolumn{3}{p{\dimexpr 0.75\textwidth-8\tabcolsep}|}{\cramit{\caption{Cost comparison}}} & 
    \raisebox{\floatsep}[\ht\strutbox][\dp\strutbox]{% adjusted for looks
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \caption{\raggedright A two line caption}
    \end{minipage}} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: thanks a lot. I also used a second \cramit to allign the Figure 1 caption's bottom to the Figure 2 caption's bottom, which worked perfectly.